# Speed-up loading multi-valued fields on Admin side?

Tags: entities, ajax

I am having multi-valued text field, which has nearly 200 values inside. On Admin side when editing node it takes HUGE amount of time to load all those values (30 seconds or more). I am trying to figure out how to speed this up - is there any possibility to load the field only as Collapsed and load insides just after clicking on the field? Values inside are being imported by feeds module so I highly doubt someone will edit them, but I also want to give them the possibility to edit.

Comment: For first read it seems intresting: 200 records for this field shouldn't be a big issue to query, it's one select statement. Also after the first load, the content entity should be cached. So all those values are going to be part of a blob.
Maybe displaying it is the issue: you could put it to a different tab, and also using big pipe.

Comment: Well actually it is Drupal Commerce site and when editing product node the product entity itself is loaded by AJAX after clicking "edit" button specifically on product entity. And the field itself is "Double field" but both are plain text format. Good to know it is probably rendering issue in browser so I can keep searching how to speed it up somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You could try for example "blackfire.io" to see what are the bottle necks of this request. (you can try any other alternative, I don't try to advertise here)
For our big homepage request it made "miracles" showing where we should optimize stuff, without that we had quite different guessings.